# copy data from one workbook to other without opening source file with certain condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have in mind a new question as:

```
Row  Columns    
7    C  V  M  G
9    X  P  M  N
```

Description:
"7" is row number written is in 2nd cell in column E
and C, V, M, G are the column names written in different cells in front of "7".
I want to map the data of C7 , V7 , M7 , and G7 to X9, P9, M9 and N9 respectively
Please help.

Actually question is like:    There is a sheet in excel workbook which has above mentioned table. table contains basically 2 rows. Row one has a value 7 (which is a row specified by me ) in the first cell of table. and other cells in the first row itself has other contents such as C , A , etc. (which are basically other cells names).    The second row basically is the destination address. description is similar to description of first row. Now what i want is that the content of C7 will be copied to content of X9, Content of V7 will be copied to P9 etc......

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Hi james , I am novice to it please help

Answer (score 0):

Imagine I have a set up as follows in Excel:

```
       E      F       G       H       I
 1     
 2     7      C       V       M       G
 3     9      X       P       M       N
```

You can copy C7 to X9, V7 to P9 etc. using the following code.

```
Sub CopyCellsUsingTable()
    Dim sourceCells As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sourceRow As Long, targetRow As Long

    Set sourceCells = Range("F2:I2")
    sourceRow = Range("E2")
    targetRow = Range("E3")

    For Each cl In sourceCells
        Range(cl.Value & sourceRow).Copy Destination:=Range(cl.Offset(1, 0).Value & targetRow)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

You may need to update the cell references.

Comment: @ALexP- Wouldn't he use the ExceuteExcel4Macro to grab the cell values w/o opening the source workbook? I am under the impression that 'Copy' will open the source file, if only briefly...

Comment: Your right - I didn't read the question fully. The code above won't work if it is copying from one workbook to another w/o opening it